# Enable to detect Active X is Enable or not in IE 9

Tags: javascript

i have a requirment in what i just need to know IS ACTIVE X IS ENABLE OR NOT In IE 9

m doing this code
 http://jsfiddle.net/ULzbW/

Can any body shade some light on this??

it is always returning TRUE

Comment: share some light on you're code or ... ?

Comment: here is the solution I got from, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178897/test-if-activex-installed-with-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample tests for the existence of the `ActiveXObject` member, which will return true even if its disabled.

In IE9 you can use [`window.external.msActiveXFilteringEnabled()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which "*Returns true if ActiveX controls are disallowed, false otherwise.*"

Answer (score 0):

You´ve tagged your question with "asp.net" so perhaps this could be of interest? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.activexcontrols

Have a look at this one as well; [Test if an ActiveX control is installed with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178897/test-if-activex-installed-with-javascript)